# iOS - Getting frame of the UIImageView/UIImage of a UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, frame, uitabbaritem

I am trying to get the `frame` of an `image` shown in a `UITaBarItem`. I can get the `view` of any `UITabBarItem` but can't able to get the frame of only image part of any `UITabBarItem`. Adding an screenshot of my views  [image]

Comment: You can get the size of tabBarItem image using `self.tabBarItem.selectedImage?.size`

Comment: @NileshRPatel I needed the frame. I have found a solution , fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For getting `UIBarButtonItem`'s view**

```
public extension UIBarButtonItem {

    var view: UIView? {
        guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else {
            return nil
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

**For getting UIImageView from `UIBarButtonItem` view:**

```
let barItemImageView = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.view.subviews.filter { view in
        view is UIImageView
        }.first
```

This will return the UIImageView of my right  UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution is

```
guard let view = self.tabBarVC?.tabBar.items?[0].valueForKey("view") as? UIView 
else 
 {
    return
 }
let frame = view.frame
```

OR

```
extension UITabBar {

func getFrameForTabAt(index: Int) -> CGRect? {
    var frames = self.subviews.compactMap { return $0 is UIControl ? $0.frame : nil }
    frames.sort { $0.origin.x < $1.origin.x }
    return frames[safe: index]
  }

}

extension Collection {

subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
    return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
}

}
```

Comment: I know about your first solution. I am using it.  I need the uiimage part only